# python opencv - filter contours by position

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I use this code to find some blobs, and pick the biggest one.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
if len(contours) != 0:
    c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

Now, I would need to change this code in a way so it returns the contour that is in the middle of the frame. (its bounding box covers the center pixel of the image)

I am not able to figure out how to do this except getting the bounding box of all contours with

```
xbox, ybox, wbox, hbox = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
```

and then checking that x and y are smaller than the centere, and x+w and y+h aare bigger than the centre. It does not look like a efficient way tough, since there can be up to 500 small controus..

Comment: Chceck out [cv2.pointPolygonTest()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1a539e8db2135af2566103705d7a5722) it does exactly what you're asking

Comment: great! thank you very much.. i can replace the key inside the max function with this one, as the one that is in the center will return 1 and all the others 0 or -1.. could you please post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract most central area in a Binary Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564868/extract-most-central-area-in-a-binary-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in OpenCV that will check if a given point is inside a contour (returns a 1), on the boundary (returns a 0) or outside (returns a -1).

[cv2.pointPolygonTest()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1a539e8db2135af2566103705d7a5722)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest this approach, maybe there is a more straightforward one. I'm writing code here, but instead giving a possible algorithm:

- Iterate over contours and draw each single contour using a mask in a binary mat (b/w and filled)
- Check if the center pixel (image width/2, image height/2) is equal to 1

That should work.

Comment: thank you! for some reason that does not work on my end. it does not draw my contours filled. i guess that there is a hole somewhere, so drawing it filled produces just the contour. but good idea anyway!

Comment: that's weird.. can you post the code you are using to draw contours ? Also a sample image. Are you using the right flag in drawcontours to fill it?